# How is the holodeck still rendering during the Voyager power drain?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, holodeck

In the *Star Trek: Voyager* episode "Night" (S05 E01), Voyager suffers a ship-wide total power drain.

How is the holodeck still rendering Tom Paris' program, albeit in darkness? He turns on a program-driven torch and you can see the screen.